# ASP.NET replay attack detection again

Tags: asp.net, security, session, cookies, replay

Ok ASP.NET WebForms is old technology now but we'll be stuck with it for the foreseeable future and I'm just trying to see if I can put in a very basic replay attack prevention mechanism. Basically we want to make sure that after a user has explicitly logged out, nobody can replay an old request and have it be automatically authenticated based on the authorization cookie, but we still want to allow using permanent authorization cookies for users that don't want to re-login each new browser session.
From what I've observed in the latter case if you exit your browser and start a new session, there is *no* session ID in the cookie headers - only the forms authorization cookie. In this case we want to allow automatic authentication (at least for GET requests).
In the "replay" case, there is a session ID in the cookie headers - but ASP.NET actually automatically recreates a new session using the same ID. Fortunately we can detect this (by checking Session.IsNewSession and Request.Headers["Cookie"] - though not, strangely, Request.Cookies which sometimes includes the session cookie even when it wasn't sent by the client), and hence it's possible to force a re-login in the case that the client has sent a session ID for a session that has been closed/abandoned when a user logged out.

But...if the replay attack deliberately omits the session ID, then there's no real way to distinguish this from a legitimate browser request when the authorization cookie is a permanent cookie.  You could at least block "POST" requests in such a case, but a replay attack could just issue a GET first to establish the new session, then follow this with a POST. 
What I *really* want is a way to determine that once a user has logged out, the cookie value that was used to authorise that session is no longer valid - I guess that would require storing something in a DB (most likely a list of currently valid cookie values), which seems like more effort than can be justified at this point. But it also seems that anything else (e.g. using hidden nonce fields on forms) is prone to a script that just emulates a user re-establishing a new session with a permanent authorization cookie, in which case they'd be able to determine the required nonce field values etc. So assuming I'm correct that something has to be stored on the server-side to keep track (essentially) of which authorization cookie values are still valid, are there any known low-footprint/well-known libraries that do this?

(BTW for now I've made use of the IsPersistent flag on the authentication ticket - if this is false, i.e. the user has explicitly chosen to only use a per-session cookie knowing they'll have re-login for their next browser session, then I can reliably block replay attacks. But if true, I only block 'POST' replays, which isn't providing much real protection but at least users that are concerned about more sophisticated replay attacks can prevent them by always choosing per-session authentication).

Answer (score 4):

Even ASP.NET Authentication says clearly that you have to have a secondary check to confirm if user is still an active logged in user (for example, we could block the user, user may have changed his password), Forms Authentication ticket does not offer any security against these things.

**UserSession has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC Session, it is just a name here**

The solution I have implemented is,

1. Create a `UserSessions` table in the database with `UserSessionID (PK, Identity) UserID (FK) DateCreated, DateUpdated`
2. FormsAuthenticationTicket has a field called UserData, you can save UserSessionID in it.

**When User Logs in**

```
public void DoLogin(){
     
     // do not call this ...
     // FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(....

     DateTime dateIssued = DateTime.UtcNow;

     var sessionID = db.CreateSession(UserID);
     var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            userName,
            dateIssued,
            dateIssued.Add(FormsAuthentication.Timeout),
            iSpersistent,
            // userData
            sessionID.ToString());

     HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(
         FormsAuthentication.CookieName,
         FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket));
     cookie.Expires = ticket.Expires;
     if(FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain!=null)
         cookie.Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain;
     cookie.Path = FormsAuthentication.CookiePath;
     Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            
}
```

**To Authorize User**

Global.asax class enables to hook into Authorize

```
public void Application_Authorize(object sender, EventArgs e){
     var user = Context.User;
     if(user == null)   
         return;

     FormsIdentity formsIdentity = user.Identity as FormsIdentity;
     long userSessionID = long.Parse(formsIdentity.UserData);
     
     string cacheKey = "US-" + userSessionID;

     // caching to improve performance
     object result = HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey];
     if(result!=null){
         // if we had cached that user is alright, we return..
         return;
     }

     // hit the database and check if session is alright
     // If user has logged out, then all UserSessions should have been
     // deleted for this user
     UserSession session = db.UserSessions
           .FirstOrDefault(x=>x.UserSessionID == userSessionID);
     if(session != null){

          // update session and mark last date
          // this helps you in tracking and you
          // can also delete sessions which were not
          // updated since long time...
          session.DateUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;
          db.SaveChanges();

          // ok user is good to login
          HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(cacheKey, "OK", 
               // set expiration for 5 mins
               DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5)..)

         // I am setting cache for 5 mins to avoid
         // hitting database for all session validation
         return;
     }

     // ok validation is wrong....


     throw new UnauthorizedException("Access denied");
 
}
```

**When User Logs out**

```
public void Logout(){

    // get the ticket..
    FormsIdentity f = Context.User.Identity as FormsIdentity;
    long sessionID = long.Parse(f.UserData);

    var session = db.UserSessions.First(x=>x.UserSessionID = sessionID);
    db.UserSession.Remove(session);
    db.SaveChanges();

    FormsAuthentication.Signout();
}
```

** When user changes password or user is blocked or user is deleted... **

```
public void ChangePassword(){

    // get the ticket..
    FormsIdentity f = Context.User.Identity as FormsIdentity;
    long sessionID = long.Parse(f.UserData);

    var session = db.UserSessions.First(x=>x.UserSessionID = sessionID);

    // delete all sessions for the same user id
    // this will force user to relogin on all other
    // devices...
    db.Database.ExecuteSql(
        "DELETE FROM UserSessions WHERE UserID=@UserID",
        new SqlParameter("@UserID", session.UserID));
}
```

Comment: Yes, something like that would definitely be a more thorough solution, just surprising that it isn't built-in to ASP.NET or that I couldn't find any well known libraries that handle it for you (even granted that it does require external storage).

Comment: I assumed ASP.NET Membership would do, but I don't think so, you have to build this on your own, in User Session, we also store device, user agent etc, which is good for analysis and logging purpose.

Comment: @AkashKava, That is an excellent solution you gave for taking care of replay attack when user has signed out before his/her session has ended. But, what about the following scenario:  `if the hacker somehow steals the forms authentication cookie while the user is logged in` and then uses this stolen cookie from another laptop to impersonate while the actual user's session has not expired. Your code would allow access to the hacker in this second scenario. Am I right or I am missing something?

Comment: @Sunil, there is no way in the world to prevent stealing forms authentication cookie. Because cookie is the only secret we have. Google/Microsoft etc try to identify GPS based on IP address/Browser UserAgent to identify hacker, but hacker on same network cannot be identified if hacker uses same IP subnet and same user-agent. You can populate UserSession with more details and verify.

Comment: @AkashKava, I agree. I think one can only try to minimize hacker attacks, but impossible to come up with a bullet proof solution when using a cookie for authentication. I was going to store a guid in forms authentication cookie and also store (username, guid)  in a local SQLite database on web server. On each request in AuthenticateRequest event, I get the guid from SQLite database and match it with that in authentication cookie. If they match then request is allowed else user is signed out. This provides an additional check against hackers.

Answer (score 0):

A Session Replay attack is, [according to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack), when you repeat same request data.

A very simple solution is to use a One Time Password" (OTP).  That is, make your session linked to an OTP.  Once the request is received, invalidate the OTP.